# Next.js - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, next.js, cors

I've inherited a Next application that has just been migrated to from React.

When visiting a page that fetches data from an AWS server, I get a CORS error -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://**************' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Within `next.config.js` I have added the following to set up a proxy -

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: '*********'
      }
    ]
  },
```

After restarting the server, the error still persists.

What else can I try so I'm able to fetch the data without getting this CORS error?

Comment: Simply adding a rewrites rule in the config isn't enough. You have to change the requests to point to `/api/*` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the aws side first. If you use apigateway to serve the data that the page fetches, apigateway has the setting for cors. This is [rest api pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

Comment: Thank you but the APIGateway settings seem to be configured correctly.

Comment: Would you like to share the cors setting details in api gateway?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin - * Access-Control-Allow-Headers - authorization content-type * 'content-type,x-amz-date,authorization,x-api-key,x-amz-security-token'
Access-Control-Allow-Methods - GET OPTIONS POST DELETE * Access-Control-Expose-Headers - date x-api-id

Comment: Access-Control-Max-Age - 300 seconds Access-Control-Allow-Credentials - No

Comment: Looks like no problem. I would like to narrow the problems step by step. Could you try putting just "Access-Control-Allow-Origin - *, Access-Control-Allow-Methods - GET OPTIONS POST DELETE" ? I wanna know if the erroe message changing.

Comment: I think it has to be an issue with my Next.js app. In the React equivalent, the data is being fetched with no CORS error.

Comment: could you try [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8544#issuecomment-770344917)? this is to avoid cors error using nextjs api.